# How to rearrange columns in an ndarray in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, numpy-ndarray

I stumbled upon what I think is a weird (or at least unintuitive) behavior of numpy and I would like to understand why it behaves that way.
Let's generate a generic array of shape (4, 3, 3).

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(4*3*3).reshape((4, 3, 3))
```

Thinking about arr as a list of four three-by-three matrices I want to now swap the first two columns of the first matrix in the list. I can just reorder the columns with an index list:

```
idx = np.array([1, 0, 2])
m = arr[0]
m[:, idx]
>>> array([[1, 0, 2],
           [4, 3, 5],
           [7, 6, 8]])
```

I see that i successfully swapped the two columns. However, if I do try to do same directly with arr, I get:

```
arr[0, :, idx]
>>> array([[1, 4, 7],
           [0, 3, 6],
           [2, 5, 8]])
```

I guess I'm doing something wrong but I don't understand this behavior.

Comment: You should use arr[0][:,idx]

Comment: This is an example of mixed basic and advanced indexing as documented at https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#combining-advanced-and-basic-indexing.  The `:` dimension has been moved to the end, transposing the result.

Answer (score 0):

This weird output is because when you are doing

```
m = arr[0]
m[:, idx]
```

then m becomes a whole different "array" with data of "arr"
but when you are doing
`arr[0, :, arr]` there arr is a list which has arrays